# Tool to capture & show Screenshot fullscreen (Mac OS style) - error message

Tags: python, pyqt, fullscreen, screenshot, breakpoints

I am trying to code an app that allows capturing screenshots. The tricky part is that it should behave like the screenshot function in Mac OS (you press a shortcut and draw a rectangle on screen, the rectangle will then be saved in a jpg file). For this project I am using PyQt4 for creating a GUI (the screenshot thing is only one feature in this application!). So far, I converted the PyQt4 form (which only contains a plain form for now) in a .py-file and tried to implement some code. 
Here is what I have so far:

When the form is loaded, it shall hide, make a screenshot of the current screen and show the image fullscreen (without borders and on top of all windows).

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(100, 100)
        Form.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu) 
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PIL import Image

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)

    Form.hide()
    QtGui.QPixmap.grabWindow(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().winId()).save('screenshot.png', 'png')
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("screenshot.png")

    lbl = QtGui.QLabel()
    lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
    lbl.setWindowFlags (QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    lbl.showFullScreen()        

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Actually this works so far, BUT after closing the app I get the following error-message in terminal:

```
    Fri Jan 25 19:19:08 my-macbook-2.local Python[35515] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument:CGSOrderWindowList
    Fri Jan 25 19:19:08 my-macbook-2.local Python[35515] <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
```

I googled "CGErrorBreakpoint()" and as far as I understood it is something debugging-related. Can anyone give me a hint on what to do with this message? Since it took me quite a couple of hours to come to this point that the app is doing what it should so far, I am hoping to be able to keep the code as it is and find a way to make python "ignore" this error-message...

Comment: How are you closing the app?

Comment: I am closing the app with CMD+Q. But the error message is showing up in terminal before I close the app. The app runs in fullscreen and always on top, so there is no way to switch to terminal while the app is running, but the error message has a time stamp. So I started the app approx. 5 minutes ago at 2pm and closed it 5minutes afterwards, but the error message in terminal had the time stamp 2 o'clock (and not 2:05pm...)

Comment: Your code runs fine here, if this is a minimal version of your code, it doesn't reproduce your issue (switch to your terminal using the `Alt`+`Tab` keys)

Comment: thank you for your reply! no, this is the comeplete code. switching to terminal with cmd+tab is not possible in this case, as the app is running "always on top". but I ran the code without the line "lbl.setWindowFlags (QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)" and then switched to teminal while the app was running and I could see the error-message as well. Apparently it has something to do with fullscreen mode: when I change line lbl.showFullScreen() to lbl.show() there is no error-message. So you can't reproduce the error-message? this is strange. are you using windows?

Comment: I tested your code on Debian. I can only suggest you to cleanup your code until you find what is causing your error, for example there's an `import` that does nothing, and you really don't need to setup the ui, it's neither doing anything relevant...